# como ver los registros por usuario

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Buenas noches, estoy haciendo un sistema de reserva de jugos en php, pero lo que sucede es que al hacer un registro de reserva, todos los usuarios pueden ver las reservas de los demás y solo quiero que vean su propia reserva.

```
//este codigo es para mostrar las reservas
 <?php
   $consulta="select * from reserva";
    $ejecutar=mysqli_query($con,$consulta);
    $i=0;
    while($fila=mysqli_fetch_array($ejecutar)){
        $dni=$fila['dni'];
        $nombres=$fila['nombre'];
        $apellidos=$fila['apellido'];
        $jugo=$fila['jugo'];
        $fecha=$fila['fecha'];
        $i++;

    ?>
```

[image: el id del usuario aparece como null en mi tabla de reservas]
[image: este es mi formulario]

[image: asi jale la columna id de la tabla login]

[image: esta es la estructura de mi tabla login]

Comment: Tendrías que filtrar la consulta por el usuario actual: `select * from reserva where codigo=el-codigo-usuario-actual;`.  Ten en cuenta que para consultas con datos externos se recomienda el uso de consultas preparadas.

Comment: Por lo que estas comentando, tu problema no es este.. es el paso anterior, que es como llenar el id en las reservas que hacen los usuarios.. yo frenaria esta consulta, y revisaria lo otro, que es lo que genera que los id esten en 0, antes de continuar.. y usar el DNI como clave de link es una idea horrible..

Comment: @gbianchi hola lo que pasa es que muestra 0 el id porque esos registros ya estabam cuando vincule el id y cuando inserte registros con el id vinculado me sale null osea siempre me sale null el 0 es porque todavia no eestaba vinculado y son registros antiguos

Comment: bueno, los registros antiguos los tenes que arreglar de alguna manera.. y el join debe ser por ID. podrias hacerlo por DNI, pero si hoy una de las personas corrige su DNI, dejarias de traerlo. Cuando uno cambia una BD, tiene que tener en cuenta esas cosas y arreglar todas las tablas.

Comment: Ahora que pusiste tus otras tablas veo que tienes un tremendo problema: un sistema de bases de datos totalmente mal concebido que se convertirá o que ya se ha convertido, en un dolor de cabeza. Creo que necesitas al menos cuatro tablas: `jugos`, `usuarios`,  `clientes`, `reservas`... y quien sabe si quizá una o varias tablas más.  Por ejemplo, en la tabla `reservas` tú no puedes repetir una y otra vez los nombres de los clientes, sino que deben tener un `id_cliente`. Cuando tengas miles de millones de reservas tendrás miles de millones de veces datos alfanuméricos repetidos.

Answer (score 0):

Usa:

```
$consulta="select * from reserva where dni='<numero de dni>'";
```

o también

```
$consulta="select * from reserva where dni='<numero de dni>' or (nombre='<nombre aquí>' and apellido='<apellido aquí>')";
```

Comment: Hola lo que pasa es queaparte de la tabla reserva tengo  otra que es login y ahi esta el id del usuario y esa es la  columna que quiero usar para filtrar pero como ves en la primera imagen me sale null

Comment: Seguro  cuando creaste la tabla no le colocaste a que el id sea "autoincrement" deberías editarla

Comment: subi una nueva foto ahi se como jale la columna id de la tabla login ¿hay algo de malo?

Comment: borre los registros y ejecute la sentencia y me sale l siguiente: ALTER TABLE reserva CHANGE id_usuario id_usuario int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT

MySQL ha dicho: Documentación
#1075 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

Comment: mi pana, yo creo que tu problema es otro... deberías subir tambien una imagen de la estructura de tu tabla de login

Comment: ya subi la foto de la estructura del login ¿que esta mal?

Comment: ok, una pregunta como tu estableces el valor en id_usuario?

Comment: cree una nueva columna y la asocie al id del login

Comment: ok, pero cuando creas una nueva reserva llenando el formulario, en el `insert` que valor le das  a id_usuario?

Comment: nada solo inserto lo que esta en el formulario fecha, dni, nombre, apellido y jugos

Comment: ahí es donde estás fallando... necesitas guardar en sesion el id del usuario cuando inicie sesion para que se la insertes a `id_usuario` cuando hagas la reserva... en mi nuevo canal... que tiene pocos dias, enseño como crear un sistema de registro y como usar las sesiones.. te puede servir.. https://youtu.be/dg8mxsWwEPM

Answer (score 0):

Debes poner la condición en el select de que solo lo vea el ususario, es decir, donde haces la variable $consulta y luego el select deber poner un 'where' igual a nombre de usuario o algo similar.
Ejemple: 
$consulta="select * from reserva where idUsuario=5978";

Comment: Hola lo que pasa es que aparte de la tabla reserva tengo  otra que es login y ahi esta el id del usuario y esa es la  columna que quiero usar para filtrar pero como ves en la primera imagen me sale null y despues de eso ¿como haria para que el select sepa que id de usuario es el actual?

Comment: Supongo que salen todas las reservas de todos los usuarios porque todos tienen el mismo id no? Primero deber poner un Id diferente para cada usuario. Luego debes hacer que la pagina valide si el dni que introduces es valido o no. Para hacerlo debes hacer: select reservas from reservas where dni in ('1','2','3',etc)

Comment: entonces deberia utilizar el dni como id?

Comment: Exacto porque al fin y al cabo el dni solo lo utilizamos para identificar y validar.

Comment: @douglas no por dios no.. mira si lo ingreso mal y vos lo tenes como clave??? por lo que veo, sabes poco de base de datos. Tu pregunta no es esta, si no como cargar el id desde la tabla login a la tabla reservas.. me equivoco??? tu problema esta un paso antes del que mostras aca.

Comment: @MohamedLbachiri, no es una muy mala idea, nunca se deben usar datos personales como claves de las tablas para linkearlas a otras.. que pasa si lo ingreso mal?

Comment: @gbianchi Entonces que no utilice el DNI(?) si lo que necesita es validar y que solo salgan unos registros, que utilice la id como primary key, que borre el campo de DNI i el usuario solo deberá introducir la id para ver sus reservas.

Comment: Vamos entiendo yo... @gbianchi

Comment: no.. el id se usa como clave principal de la tabla.. el dni es un dato de la persona, no tiene nada que ver con esto...

Comment: Entonces entiendo que el DNI debería hacer referencia al id para ver si esta registrado en el sistema para mostrar unas reservas u otras

Comment: no.. la tabla de el esta mal.. su problema se resuelve simplemente arreglando la tabla que tiene y conectandolas por ID.